# ReactJS получить данные из json файла

Tags: массивы, json, reactjs

Данные в json

```
{
  author: 'People1',
  text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.',
  bigtext: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.'
},
{
  author: 'People2',
  text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.',
  bigtext: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.'
}
```

Как мне получить оттуда объекты и сохранить в массив?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался через require
let example = require('./example.json');